# ServerManager How to get site's physical path on disk?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

How I can get physical path of site on a disk ?

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 

var sites = serverManager.Sites; 
foreach (Site site in sites) { 
         Console.WriteLine(site.Name); // This will return the WebSite name
        //but how i get it's path on disc ??????

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
ServerManager m = new ServerManager();  
m.Sites["default web site"].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath;
```

basically every site has a "root application" which must have a "root virtual directory".

Comment: little update Applications not work ["/"] update was 
currentlySite.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath and full example  
using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
            {
                SiteCollection lstSite = manager.Sites;
                foreach (var item in lstSite)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);   Console.WriteLine(item.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath);
                } 
            }

Answer (score 0):

To improve a bit what others wrote, remember if you have multiple application pools pr site you get multiple directories.

```
using (var iisManager = new ServerManager())
{
    SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;
    foreach (var site in sites)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
        
        foreach(var app in site.Applications)
        {
              foreach (var virt in app.VirtualDirectories)
              {
                Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to get path

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) 
{ 

    var sites = serverManager.Sites; 
    foreach (Site site in sites) 
    { 

        foreach (Application app in site.Applications)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("path: {0}", app.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get something like C:\inetpub\wwwroot .

Comment: This may have been down votes but it's the simplest way to do iteration of sites in IIS7

Comment: The question is asking for a physical path, this only provides the virtual path.