# Finding absolute path to website from a Windows service or desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Windows service and a desktop app that is located on the same machine as my website but is not part of the site's directory. Is there a way to determine the absolute path of the website from the service or desktop app?

I came across this post:
[ServerManager How to get site's physical path on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431703/servermanager-how-to-get-sites-physical-path-on-disk)

but three people commented that the ServerManager has some serious memory leaks, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the service and app know the URL of the website, simply output the absolute network and local paths in XML on an aspx driven page on the website and then read the XML in the app or service.