# Get IIS Express Physical Path from Command Line

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I have a project which physical path is: `C:\Users\username\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\`

How do I obtain that from the command line? Either with CMD, wmic or powershell it doesn't matter.

I am running the IIS Express server manually, with: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe` in case that helps.

For the IIS Server I can do this:

```
cat C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config | sls "physicalPath"
```

and then:

```
dir env:SystemDrive
```

I am not sure if there is another option

Comment: Try this link may be ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432322/5212566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServerManager How to get site's physical path on disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431703/servermanager-how-to-get-sites-physical-path-on-disk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best solution I have found:

```
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$env:systemroot\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll")

$iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager "$env:systemroot\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config"

foreach ($site in $iis.Sites) { echo $site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath; }
```